# Firebase shows error: To make change, ask a project owner for necessary change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Firebase shows following error when I try to add sha1 in firebase console for phone authentication.

> To make a change, ask a project owner for necessary change

Even though, I am one of the owners. 
Here is the [image link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qvBRo0q5okEY9RpH4ju_54isn1wt4Fmg) of error. 
Can anyone help ?

Comment: *firebaser here* If you're a project owner, you should have permission to change that field already. If that isn't the case, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Is this an Android app that you created and added to Firebase or did someone else take on the task of adding it to Firebase? It looks like you are required to enter a SHA-1 certificate.

Comment: @IshaanJavali Yes, I need to enter SHA-1 certificate but I can not enter due to the erroe. And I am the owner of project and when I tried to add SHA-1, I got the error.

Comment: I've seen multiple reports of this. I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug (which it sounds like to me at this point), and will update here when I hear more.

Comment: It seems that this error message is also shown if the SHA is already used in another project.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. yes, the problem was ,I was generating the sha from same keystore that was added in the another project.

Comment: Good to hear. That error message is mighty confusing (that's a nice version of saying "it's wrong"). There were quite a few reports of this problem in the past few days, so I wonder if something changed recently.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes. But, I have another issue too. Can you help me? I can not add debug SHA due to the same error.

Comment: Sorry Riddhi, I'm not sure what's the cause of that. If you're certain it's not being used elsewhere, I'd open a new question with the exact details of this problem in hopes somebody else knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This error message is also shown if the SHA is already used in another project. This is indeed not at all clear from the message, so we'll get that fixed. But in the meantime, you'll have to find the other project that is using the SHA and remove it from there before adding it to this project.

Comment: Are the checks for SHA-1 fingerprints a global thing or per account basis? What would happen if there's the same SHA for different accounts?